# Functions with equivalent Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

Given two functions $f(x),g(x)$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying $f(x+P)=f(x)$ and $g(x+P)=g(x)$ for $P\in\mathbb{R}$, consider their Fourier transformation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{f}(k)=\frac{1}{P}\int_{0}^{P}dx e^{ikx2\pi/P}f(x), \hspace{10pt} \tilde{g}(k)=\frac{1}{P}\int_{0}^{P}dx e^{ikx2\pi/P}g(x).
\end{eqnarray}
Now, if $\tilde{f}(k)=\tilde{g}(k)$, what can be said about the functions $f(x),g(x)$? Of course if $f(x)=g(x)$ the relation is clear, but the question is if given two FT of two functions, with equivalent Fourier decomposition, it always holds that $f(x)=g(x)$; I am somewhat inclined to think this is not necessarily the case but I would like to know about this in a direct way, if there are any theorems about it.

Comment: The functions must be in a space which is Fourier transformable for it to be unique. 

If you are trying to transform something which isn't well behaved enough to live in such a space, then there are many ways in which you can get different functions. But the functions will be the same if they were both Fourier transformable in the first place.

Comment: They must be the same. Another way of putting the problem is - if all Fourier coefficients of a function are 0 is the function 0 (almost everywhere 0). This follows from density of trigonometric polynomials in any normal space like $L^1$ or $C(K)$,

Comment: The problem I am facing is to make an identification of $\frac{1}{P}\int_{0}^{P}e^{ikx}f(x) = \frac{1}{P}\int_{0}^{P}dx e^{ikx}\left( g^{*}(x)\frac{dg(x)}{dx}  - g^{*}(x)f(x)g(x)\right) $ between the LHS and the RHS; then one can obtain a differential equation for the $g(x)$ functions on the RHS by the shake of the arguments exposed above? e.g. by equating the integrands.